# How do I factorize $210a^6m^3-107a^4m^2l+18a^2l^2m-l^3$ into a term composed of multiplications of polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I need to factorize $210a^6m^3-107a^4m^2l+18a^2l^2m-l^3$ into a term composed of multiplications of polynomials. WolframAlpha gave me the following answer $(6a^2m-l)(l-5a^2m)(l-7a^2m)$. Is there a method I could use to obtain this (or the factorization of any other polynomial? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: with $z = \cfrac{a^2m}{l}$ the expression writes as:

$$
l^3 \cdot \left(210 z^3 - 107 z^2+18 z -1\right)
$$

Checking the cubic for [rational roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) finds the factorization:

$$
210 z^3 - 107 z^2+18 z -1 = (7 z - 1) (6 z - 1) (5 z - 1)
$$

Comment: Thanks! But how should I proceed in the case of an arbitrary polynomial that I know can be factorized in such a way?

Comment: @TempManAcc That's way too broad a question. If you know or expect linear factors with rational coefficients, try the rational root theorem. Otherwise if it's solvable by radicals, try finding the roots. Otherwise if you have reasons to guess a factorization of a certain form, try using undetermined coefficients. But there is no general technique to cover *all* cases.